# Infinite series representation for root of polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, sequences-and-series

Given a polynomial $p(x)=a_nx^n+\dots+a_1x+a_0$, can every root of the polynomial be represented as $\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k$ with the $b_k$'s being a function of $a_0,\dots,a_n$ using only elementary operations of arithmetic and taking roots?

Comment: What field are the $a_i$ over, and what coefficients are the $b_i$ allowed to have?

Comment: I don't want to restrict that (if different fields yield different answers that's very interesting) but one can assume we talk about the field of rational numbers, for a concrete case.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but: Would this not be equivalent of asking about finding a sequence $c_k$ (instead of a series) that converges to the root, each term being an 'elemental' function of $a_i$? IF so, couldn't we think $c_k$ as the values provided by some (complex) root-finding iterative algorithm (say, Durand–Kerner)?

Comment: At least for $p(x)=x^5+x+a$ this seems to be possible using [Bring's radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical#Series_representation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is true at least formally if you allow the $b_i$ to have coefficients in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. This is because, if $K$ is an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$, then the field of [Puiseux series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series) with coefficients in $K$ is also algebraically closed, and by iterating this construction for each coefficient $a_i$ I think we get the desired result abstractly, although I am not sure what one can say about actual (as opposed to formal) convergence.

Comment: According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series there is actual convergence in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Akhil: this is true in sufficiently small neighborhoods, but I don't know if one can get global convergence even for quintic polynomials. See, for example, the explicit series roots given at http://qchu.wordpress.com/2010/10/08/update-and-the-combinatorics-of-quintic-equations/ .

Comment: Sorry, I only meant convergence near the origin. I see that is not quite what the OP wants though.

Answer (score 5):

The difficult part is to get a good a priori estimate $\Omega\subset{\mathbb C}$ of the set $S$ of roots. Starting with any $z_0\in\Omega$, e.g., with rational coordinates, Newton's rule $$z_{n+1}:=z_n-{p(z_n)\over p'(z_n)}\qquad(n\geq 0)\ ,$$
i.e., $$b_0=z_0, \qquad b_{n+1}:=-{p(z_n)\over p'(z_n)}\qquad(n\geq 0),$$ provides a series $\sum_{k\geq 0} b_k$ converging to a point $\zeta\in S$ where the $b_k$ depend rationally on the coefficients of $p$ (and the chosen point $z_0$).

There is a famous paper by Smale on this:  "The fundamental theorem of algebra and complexity theory", Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society ${\bf 4}$ (1981), 1–36.

Comment: In this approach it seems the problem is to find a radical function of the coefficients that makes for a good choice of $z_0$. No obvious candidates come to mind...

Comment: Here's [the direct link to the article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0273-0979-1981-14858-8).

Comment: which begs the question: is there some iterative algorithm for finding all the complex roots of a polynomial (including the choosing of the starting point/s) that is guaranteed to find all roots? (disregarding numerical errors)